# What parts do I need to upgrade my drivetrain?

Tags: drivetrain

I have a Cannondale M300 with a 7-speed drivetrain.  The parts are fairly worn and I am considering converting to a 9-speed as 7-speed components are getting harder to find.

What parts do I need to consider to replace the drive-train?

Comment: What brand components are on it now?

Comment: Currently STX-RC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of your setup, you may need to replace:

- Chain
- Front Shifter
- Rear Derailleur
- Cassette Hub
- Cassette

You may also have to change your dropout spacing, and may need to re-dish the wheel to maintain proper alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Been a long time since I did my 7 - 9 conversion but I believe I needed:

1. new cassette
2. shifter for rear
3. new cassette mount thing (not the hub but I'm blanking on the name)

You may also need a new front shifter since a 9 speed chain is thinner but I managed to make both front and rear work just fine. I squeezed the front one down a bit to make it a bit narrower. Been using mine for 7 years or so now.

Comment: Won't he need a new chain as well, then?